Is it possible to integrate $\int \frac{x^2 - 2x + 3}{x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1} \ dx$ using methods typical of undergraduate calculus?
I was doing a calculus problem and got to this final integral: $$\int\limits_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2 - 2x + 3}{x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1} \ dx.$$ Calculators are supposed to be used for these problems, so I just input the final integral into my calculator and got the result. However, I wondered if there is a method to integrate it manually.
For simplicity, let's remove the limits and focus on the indefinite form. The nominator suggests a $(x-1)$ dummy variable, so I tried rewriting the integrand in terms of $u = (x-1)$ and got: $$\int \frac{u^2 + 2}{u^4 + 3u^3 + 4u^2 + 2u + 1} \ du$$
This still doesn't seem to lead to any well-known forms that I'm aware of. My question is, is it possible to integrate this using knowledge of undergraduate calculus, and if yes, I'd like to hear some directions to tackle it. Thank you!

Removing the bounds rarely leads to simplicity. Indefinite integrals are usually much harder than definite ones.

@NinadMunshi Thanks! Integrating the indefinite form is what interests me the most I guess. :P

In this case for example, instead multiply the numerator and denominator of the original integral by $(x+1)$. With the bounds, you can now use geometric series to integrate. Without it, you cannot justify geometric series.

I would guess the answer is yes, but it's going to take 2-3 pages of working.

In general a totally mechanical way to find an antiderivative for a function like this is by partial fraction decomposition. The denominator does factorise nicely as it's a factor of $x^5 + 1$. (This will take a lot of calculation though).

@IzaakvanDongen Yes, I also just tried that approach and found myself having to find the integral of $\dfrac{1}{x^5 + 1}$, which looks very nice but I'm still figuring out how to deal with it.

You can write the denominator as $(x^2 - a x + 1)(x^2 - b x + 1)$ for some constants $a$ and $b$. Then use partial fractions.

The point about partial fraction decomposition is that you can split the integrand into fractions whose denominators are real quadratics, and then apply standard techniques to those. In this case those real quadratics should be $x^2 - 2x \cos(\pi / 5) + 1$ and $x^2 - 2x \cos(3\pi / 5) + 1$. (Or in other words, $x^2 - \varphi x + 1$ and $x^2 + \varphi^{-1} x + 1$ where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio). Again, it's messy!!

yes, like others said PFD looks like the way (unfortunately) here. https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/partialfractions.aspx

Since$$x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1=\frac{x^5+1}{x+1},$$the roots of $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$ are the fifth roots of $-1$ other than $-1$. That is, they are $e^{\pi i/5}$, $e^{3\pi i/5}$, $e^{7\pi i/5}$, and $e^{9\pi i/5}$; besides, $e^{9\pi i/5}=\overline{e^{\pi i/5}}$ and $e^{7\pi i/5}=\overline{e^{3\pi i/5}}$. So\begin{align}x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1&=\left(x-e^{\pi i/5}\right)\left(x-e^{9\pi i/5}\right)\left(x-e^{3\pi i/5}\right)\left(x-e^{7\pi i/5}\right)\\&=\left(x^2-2\cos\left(\frac\pi5\right)x+1\right)\left(x^2-2\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}5\right)x+1\right)\\&=\left(x^2-\frac{1+\sqrt5}2x+1\right)\left(x^2-\frac{1-\sqrt5}2x+1\right).\end{align}So, you can write$$\frac{x^2-2x+3}{x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1}\quad\text{as}\quad\frac{Ax+B}{x^2-\frac{1+\sqrt5}2x+1}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2-\frac{1-\sqrt5}2x+1}.$$In order to get the coefficients $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, you sum these two fractions on the right and the asserting that this sum is equal to the expression that you want to integrate, you solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}B+D=3\\A+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}2B+C-\frac{1+\sqrt5}2D=-2\\\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}2A+B-\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}2C+D=1\\A+C=0.\end{array}\right.$$You will get that$$A=-\frac2{\sqrt5},\ B=\frac{15-\sqrt5}{10},\ C=\frac2{\sqrt5},\text{ and }D=\frac{15+\sqrt5}{10}.$$It follows from this that\begin{multline}\int\frac{x^2-2x+3}{x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1}\,\mathrm dx=\\=-\frac{\log\left(2x^2-\left(1+\sqrt5\right)x+2\right)}{\sqrt5}+\frac15\left(\sqrt5-1\right)\sqrt{2\left(5+\sqrt5\right)}\arctan\left(\frac{4x-\sqrt5-1}{\sqrt{10-2 \sqrt5}}\right)+\\+\frac{\log \left(2x^2-\left(1-\sqrt5\right)x+2\right)}{\sqrt5}+\frac25\sqrt{2\left(5+\sqrt5\right)} \arctan\left(\frac{4x+\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{2\left(5+\sqrt5\right)}}\right).\end{multline}

Another great technique (using symmetry of coefficients) to factorize the polynomial in denominator is presented here. It was also your answer :)

Thank you very much! I've got the idea and will try to do it again after dinner!

This is the only way I can think of solving this.
(Maybe you have made a mistake along the way and the final integral is wrong because this integral is not elementary at all.)
First we see that
$$x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1=(x^2+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}x+1)(x^2-\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}x+1)$$
So we can now perform partial fraction decomposition and easily get
$$I=\int \frac{4x+3\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{5}(2x^2+(\sqrt{5}-1)x+2)}-\frac{4x-2\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{5}(2x^2+(-\sqrt{5}-1)x+2)}dx$$
Factoring out the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ we get
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (\int\frac{4x+3\sqrt{5}+1}{2x^2+(\sqrt{5}-1)x+2}dx-\int\frac{4x-2\sqrt{5}+1}{2x^2+(-\sqrt{5}-1)x+2}dx)$$
For
$$\int\frac{4x+3\sqrt{5}+1}{2x^2+(\sqrt{5}-1)x+2}dx$$
We substitute $u=2x^2+(\sqrt{5}-1)x+2$ and $du=(4x+\sqrt{5}-1)dx$ So
$$I_1=\int\frac{1}{u}du= \log(u)=\log(2x^2+(\sqrt{5}-1)x+2)$$
For
$$\int \frac{4x-2\sqrt{5}+1}{2x^2+(-\sqrt{5}-1)x+2}dx$$
First we complete the square in the denominator.
$$I_2=\int \frac{4x-2\sqrt{5}+1}{(\sqrt{2}x+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2^{2/3}
})^2-\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)^2}{8}+2}dx$$
We substitute $t=\frac{4x+\sqrt{5}-1}{2^{2/3}\sqrt{2-\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)^2}{8}}}$ and $dt=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2-\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)^2}{8}}}dx$ So
$$I_2=\int \frac{\sqrt{2-\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)^2}{8}}}{\sqrt{2}(\frac{16-(\sqrt{5}-1)^2t^2}{8}-\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)^2}{8}+2)}dt$$
This simplifies to
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)^2}{8}}}\int\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt$$
We know that $\int \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\tan^{-1}(t)$ So
$$I_2=\frac{\tan^{-1}(t)}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)^2}{8}}}=\frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{4x+\sqrt{5}-1}{2^{3/2}\sqrt{2-\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)^2}{8}}})}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)^2}{8}}}$$
Plugging in the solved integrals we get
$$\int\frac{4x+\sqrt{5}-1}{2x^2+(\sqrt{5}-1)x+2}dx+(2\sqrt{5}+2)\int\frac{1}{2x^2+(\sqrt{5}-1)x+1}=\log(2x^2+(\sqrt{5}-1)x+2)+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{4x+\sqrt{5}-1}{2^{3/2}\sqrt{2-\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)^2}{8}}})}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)^2}{8}}}$$
Now solving
$$\int\frac{4x-\sqrt{5}-1}{2x^2+(-\sqrt{5}-1)x+2}dx $$
Substitute $u=2x^2+(-\sqrt{5}-1)x+2$ and $du=4x-\sqrt{5}-1$
$$=\int\frac{1}{u}du=\log(u)=\log(2x^2+(-\sqrt{5}-1)x+2)$$
And for
$$\int\frac{1}{2x^2+(-\sqrt{5}-1)x+2}dx$$
Complete the square
$$\int\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2}x+\frac{-\sqrt{5}-1}{2^{3/2}})^2-\frac{(-\sqrt{5}-1)^2}{8}+2}dx$$
Substitute $u=\frac{4x-\sqrt{5}-1}{2^{3/2}\sqrt{2-\frac{(\sqrt{5}+1)^2}{8}}}$ and $du=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2-\frac{(\sqrt{5}+1)^2}{8}}}dx$ and simplify
$$\frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{4x-\sqrt{5}-1}{2^{3/2}\sqrt{2-\frac{(\sqrt{5}+1)^2}{8}}})}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\frac{(\sqrt{5}+1)^2}{8}}}$$
And finally plugging in the solved integrals we get
$$I=-\frac{\log\left(2x^2-\left(1+\sqrt5\right)x+2\right)}{\sqrt5}+\frac15\left(\sqrt5-1\right)\sqrt{2\left(5+\sqrt5\right)}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4x-\sqrt5-1}{\sqrt{10-2 \sqrt5}}\right)+\\+\frac{\log \left(2x^2-\left(1-\sqrt5\right)x+2\right)}{\sqrt5}+\frac25\sqrt{2\left(5+\sqrt5\right)} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4x+\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{2\left(5+\sqrt5\right)}}\right)$$

Hi, thank you very much! The final integral was actually correct. As mentioned, I was supposed to use the calculator when I reached that point. I was just interested in how to integrate it manually. I think I've got the idea of how to do it from José's answer. Yours looks similar, but I will review your exact steps more carefully once I attempt it later tonight! Thanks again!

Recognize $x^2-2x+3=2(x^2-x+1)+(1-x^2)
$
to split the integral as follows
$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2 - 2x + 3}{x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1} \ dx=I_1 +I_2$$
where
\begin{align}
I_1= &\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2(x^2-x+1)}{x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1} dx=2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^3+1}{x^5  + 1}  dx\\
 = & \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^3+1}{x^5  + 1}  dx
 =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{x^5  + 1} dx=\frac{2\pi}5 \csc\frac\pi5\\
\\
 I_2= &\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-x^2}{x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1} dx \\
 = &\int_{0}^{1} \frac{d(x+\frac1x)}{1+(x+ \frac1x )-(x+\frac1x)^2}
=\frac4{\sqrt5}\ln \phi
\end{align}
Thus, the integral evaluates to $I= \frac{2\pi}5 \csc\frac\pi5+ \frac4{\sqrt5}\ln \phi$.

This looks very neat! Thank you very much! I will take the time after Wed to review this more carefully!
